# curl with --netrc-file option does not work but with -d it does

Tags: bash, curl

I ran into a problem when trying to use curl with --netrc-file option in my bash script. When I just put `curl -d "username=MYUSR&password=MYPSWD" https://st-machinexxx/api -c cookies.txt`
then it works fine. But `curl --netrc-file configfile.txt https://st-machinexxx/api -c cookies.txt`
causes a HTTP ERROR 401. What can be the reason? I was trying to set athentication method by adding --digest, --negotiate and --ntlm as well as set some headers, but didn't help. I am using curl 7.29.0, configfile.txt contains just three lines:

```
machine st-machinexxx
login MYUSR
password MYPSWD
```

Comment: `--netrc-file` is for authenticating *with* the HTTP server; `-d` provides data that a program gets *from* the HTTP server.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I don't understand. `man curl` says, that `-d` "Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server(...)". I used `-d` for authenticating with server and that is ok., but I want to apply a little bit safer method with --netrc-file and that doesn't work, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the indentation of your `netrc` file. See this: https://superuser.com/a/1784420/1799443

For some unknown reason (possibly for not recognizing the carriage return), if you don't use indentation you will get this error. Also, I recommend you read about `--crlf` and `--use-ascii` options here: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--crlf

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please clarify your solution a bit more. Links alone are only helpful as long as the site didn't move.